# C# Selenium error - The operation has timed out

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I started getting a timeout on `get_Displayed` on a build server while working on a developer pc.

```
> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL 
http://localhost:31942/session/92fcd47749af008b115456dff0255911/execute/sync timed out after 60 seconds.
  ----> System.Net.WebException : The operation has timed out.
  Stack Trace:
     at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.MakeHttpRequest(HttpRequestInfo requestInfo)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement.get_Displayed()
```

```
        while (!LoginUsername.Displayed)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        LoginUsername.SendKeys(username);
        LoginPassword.SendKeys(password);
        LoginSubmit.Click();
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
```

Comment: C# 2 was released in 2006 and targeted .NET 2. That's almost certainly *not* what you're using. Did you mean .NET Core 2 perhaps?

Comment: Sorry wrong tag

Comment: Can you please Described some code so i can check on it, and solved this problem.

Comment: ChromeDriver timeout calling LoginUsername.Displayed if i remove that line on build server code run fine. but code work with calling displayed on my laptop

Comment: hello dan, please add some more code like where you define webdriver, and what is LoginUsername? how can i know, please put your proper code i'll give you solution within 10 minutes.